# Android studious autoLink = map not working with Latvian addresses

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, maps, autolink

So I'm making business card for one local bar and I have run into problem with autoLink.

For some reason, map autoLink does not work with Latvian addresses. I tested same approach with US address (copied the formatting google gave me) and it worked just fine. When I do the same with Latvia addresses autoLink won't respond to it.

Here is my xml code:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/address"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/address"
android:autoLink="map"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:layout_below="@id/about"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/loc"
android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
/>
```

And strings code:

```
<string name="address">Kalēju iela 51, Centra rajons, Rīga, LV-1050, Latvija </string>
```

I tried writing address in US like format "51 Kaleju Street Riga, LV-1050", but it didn't work. I also tried bunch of other variations that came in my mind, but all unsuccessful.

Maybe someone has experience with this or just knows how to fix this? Maybe some java code is needed?

Thanks in advance,
Sandra.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck with the same problem.

But what I found:
"They haven't optimized the android:autoLink maps to India still. Works with US addresses only."

I guess the same goes for Latvia as for India - still doesn't work.
I think we have to use Intents ;(